# Converting int to string in C

Tags: c

I am using the `itoa()` function to convert an `int` into `string`, but it is giving an error:

```
undefined reference to `itoa'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the reason? Is there some other way to perform this conversion?

Comment: yes I have included stdlib.h but its sill not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use `snprintf`, it is more portable than `itoa`.

[itoa is not part of standard C, nor is it part of standard C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/); but, a lot of compilers and associated libraries support it.

Example of `sprintf`

```
char* buffer = ... allocate a buffer ...
int value = 4564;
sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
```

Example of `snprintf`

```
char buffer[10];
int value = 234452;
snprintf(buffer, 10, "%d", value);
```

Both functions are similar to `fprintf`, but output is written into an array rather than to a stream. The difference between `sprintf` and `snprintf` is that `snprintf` guarantees no buffer overrun by writing up to a maximum number of characters that can be stored in the `buffer`.

Comment: Another difference between `sprintf` adn `snprintf` is the Standard they are described in: C89 (and later) for `sprintf`; C99 for snprintf. Notably the Windows library lacks the `snprintf` function or has a different behaviour than the Standard describes.

Comment: Is `snprintf`putting `'\0'` to my arrays last element ? So i can know where it is ending ?

Comment: @MuhamedCicak It will add the terminating '\0' provided that the value written and the termination '\0' can fit within the size parameter.  You should check the return value, to see if it is the inputted size or greater.  If it is the inputted size or greater, the result was truncated, and the buffer might not have a terminating '\0' character

Comment: @EdwinBuck This is correct, but to further clarify, i would say that you will always have a '\0' even when "truncation" occurs (unless you provided a size of zero, but that usage is only meaningful to determine the needed buffer size before making a second call). To be totally correct, one need to also check whether the returned value is negative, which happens "if an encoding error occurred" (whatever that means). In case of error, nothing specifies that the buffer will at least start with '\0' and horrors may ensue when trying to use it!

Answer (score 9):

Use `snprintf` - it is standard an available in every compilator. Query it for the size needed by calling it with `NULL, 0` parameters. Allocate one character more for null at the end.

```
int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", x );
char* str = malloc( length + 1 );
snprintf( str, length + 1, "%d", x );
...
free(str);
```

Answer (score 8):

Before I continue, I must warn you that `itoa` is NOT an ANSI function — it's not a standard C function. You should use `sprintf` to convert an `int` into a string.

`itoa` takes three arguments.

- The first one is the integer to be converted.
- The second is a pointer to an array of characters - this is where the string is going to be stored. The program may crash if you pass in a `char *` variable, so you should pass in a normal sized char array and it will work fine.
- The last one is NOT the size of the array, but it's the BASE of your number - base 10 is the one you're most likely to use.

The function returns a pointer to its second argument — where it has stored the converted string.

`itoa` is a very useful function, which is supported by some compilers - it's a shame it isn't support by all, unlike `atoi`.

If you still want to use `itoa`, here is how should you use it.  Otherwise, you have another option using `sprintf` (as long as you want base 8, 10 or 16 output):

```
char str[5];
printf("15 in binary is %s\n",  itoa(15, str, 2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Better use sprintf(),

```
char stringNum[20];
int num=100;
sprintf(stringNum,"%d",num);
```

Comment: 50 is a bit overkill - even a 64bit integer doesn't need 49 characters. and you have a typo in your sprintf call

Comment: Minor: `char stringNum[21];` needed for  `-power(2,63)`.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning in this context, for rookies and pros alike, that using fixed buffer sizes and `sprintf` is considered _bad practice_, and one of the most common root causes of memory corruption, security issues/exploits and other weird bugs. If possible, always use `snprintf` whenever you format strings into a buffer, and make sure you keep track of the size of the buffer used (also consider the trailing \0!)

Answer (score 3):

Usually [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) is the way to go:

```
char str[16]; // could be less but i'm too lazy to look for the actual the max length of an integer
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", your_integer);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own `itoa`, with this function:

```
void my_utoa(int dataIn, char* bffr, int radix){
int temp_dataIn;
temp_dataIn = dataIn;
int stringLen=1;

while ((int)temp_dataIn/radix != 0){
    temp_dataIn = (int)temp_dataIn/radix;
    stringLen++;
}
//printf("stringLen = %d\n", stringLen);
temp_dataIn = dataIn;
do{
    *(bffr+stringLen-1) = (temp_dataIn%radix)+'0';
    temp_dataIn = (int) temp_dataIn / radix;
}while(stringLen--);}
```

and this is example:

```
char buffer[33];
int main(){
  my_utoa(54321, buffer, 10);
  printf(buffer);
  printf("\n");

  my_utoa(13579, buffer, 10);
  printf(buffer);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will not work as `itoa`, since there's no code to handle negative numbers with base 10.

Answer (score 2):

```
void itos(int value, char* str, size_t size) {
    snprintf(str, size, "%d", value);
}
```

..works with [call by reference](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference). Use it like this e.g.:

```
int someIntToParse;
char resultingString[length(someIntToParse)];

itos(someIntToParse, resultingString, length(someIntToParse));
```

now `resultingString` will hold your C-'string'.

Comment: This will work for decimal(base 10) conversion only.

Answer (score 2):

```
char string[something];
sprintf(string, "%d", 42);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar implementation to Ahmad Sirojuddin but slightly different semantics. From a security perspective, any time a function writes into a string buffer, the function should really "know" the size of the buffer and refuse to write past the end of it. I would guess its a part of the reason you can't find itoa anymore.

Also, the following implementation avoids performing the module/devide operation twice.

```
char *u32todec( uint32_t    value,
                char        *buf,
                int         size)
{
    if(size > 1){
        int i=size-1, offset, bytes;
        buf[i--]='\0';
        do{
            buf[i--]=(value % 10)+'0';
            value = value/10;
        }while((value > 0) && (i>=0));
        offset=i+1;
        if(offset > 0){
            bytes=size-i-1;
            for(i=0;i<bytes;i++)
                buf[i]=buf[i+offset];
        }
        return buf;
    }else
        return NULL;
}
```

The following code both tests the above code and demonstrates its correctness:

```
int main(void)
{
    uint64_t acc;
    uint32_t inc;
    char buf[16];
    size_t bufsize;
    for(acc=0, inc=7; acc<0x100000000; acc+=inc){
        printf("%u: ", (uint32_t)acc);
        for(bufsize=17; bufsize>0; bufsize/=2){
            if(NULL != u32todec((uint32_t)acc, buf, bufsize))
                printf("%s ", buf);
        }
        printf("\n");
        if(acc/inc > 9)
            inc*=7;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this example

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for itoa() call
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {
    int num = 145;
    char buf[5];

    // convert 123 to string [buf]
    itoa(num, buf, 10);

    // print our string
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

see this [link](http://daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/11049) having other examples.

Comment: see this link it having some examples, http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/11049

Answer (score 0):

Like Edwin suggested, use **snprintf**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int n = 1234;
    char buf[10];
    snprintf(buf, 10, "%d", n);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use itoa, you need to include the standard library header.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I also believe that if you're on Windows (using MSVC), then `itoa` is actually `_itoa`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt(v=VS.100).aspx

Then again, since you're getting a message from `collect2`, you're likely running GCC on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

itoa() function is not defined in ANSI-C, so not implemented by default for some platforms ([Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162733/atoi-is-a-standard-function-but-itoa-is-not-why)).

s(n)printf() functions are easiest replacement of itoa(). However itoa (integer to ascii) function can be used as a better overall solution of integer to ascii conversion problem.

itoa() is also better than s(n)printf() as performance depending on the implementation. A reduced itoa (support only 10 radix) implementation as an example: [Reference Link](https://github.com/wsq003/itoa_for_linux/blob/master/itoa.c)

Another complete itoa() implementation is below ([Reference Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-itoa/)):

```
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>

// A utility function to reverse a string 
char *reverse(char *str)
{
  char *p1, *p2;

  if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;
  for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
  {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
  }
  return str;
}
// Implementation of itoa() 
char* itoa(int num, char* str, int base) 
{ 
    int i = 0; 
    bool isNegative = false; 
  
    /* Handle 0 explicitely, otherwise empty string is printed for 0 */
    if (num == 0) 
    { 
        str[i++] = '0'; 
        str[i] = '\0'; 
        return str; 
    } 
  
    // In standard itoa(), negative numbers are handled only with  
    // base 10. Otherwise numbers are considered unsigned. 
    if (num < 0 && base == 10) 
    { 
        isNegative = true; 
        num = -num; 
    } 
  
    // Process individual digits 
    while (num != 0) 
    { 
        int rem = num % base; 
        str[i++] = (rem > 9)? (rem-10) + 'a' : rem + '0'; 
        num = num/base; 
    } 
  
    // If number is negative, append '-' 
    if (isNegative) 
        str[i++] = '-'; 
  
    str[i] = '\0'; // Append string terminator 
  
    // Reverse the string 
    reverse(str); 
  
    return str; 
}
```

Another complete itoa() implementatiton: [Reference Link](https://www.techiedelight.com/implement-itoa-function-in-c/)

An itoa() usage example below ([Reference Link](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-itoa-function/)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
    int a=54325;
    char buffer[20];
    itoa(a,buffer,2);   // here 2 means binary
    printf("Binary value = %s\n", buffer);
 
    itoa(a,buffer,10);   // here 10 means decimal
    printf("Decimal value = %s\n", buffer);
 
    itoa(a,buffer,16);   // here 16 means Hexadecimal
    printf("Hexadecimal value = %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(InNumber == 0)
{
    return TEXT("0");
}

const int32 CharsBufferSize = 64; // enought for int128 type
TCHAR ResultChars[CharsBufferSize];
int32 Number = InNumber;

// Defines Decreasing/Ascending ten-Digits to determine each digit in negative and positive numbers.
const TCHAR* DigitalChars = TEXT("9876543210123456789");
constexpr int32 ZeroCharIndex = 9; // Position of the ZERO character from the DigitalChars.
constexpr int32 Base = 10; // base system of the number.

// Convert each digit of the number to a digital char from the top down.
int32 CharIndex = CharsBufferSize - 1;
for(; Number != 0 && CharIndex > INDEX_NONE; --CharIndex)
{
    const int32 CharToInsert = ZeroCharIndex + (Number % Base);
    ResultChars[CharIndex] = DigitalChars[CharToInsert];
    Number /= Base;
}

// Insert sign if is negative number to left of the digital chars.
if(InNumber < 0 && CharIndex > INDEX_NONE)
{
    ResultChars[CharIndex] = L'-';
}
else
{
    // return to the first digital char if is unsigned number.
    ++CharIndex;
}

// Get number of the converted chars and construct string to return.
const int32 ResultSize = CharsBufferSize - CharIndex;
return TString{&ResultChars[CharIndex], ResultSize};
```

Comment: It would be good if you can explain the answer instead of just posting the code.