# Store an integer value in a character array in C

Tags: c, char, int

It is a very trivial question but I don't know why I am not getting the correct output. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
char sendBuffer[1000];
int count=0:
while(count<10)
{
    sendBuffer[0]=count;
    sendBuffer[1]='a';
    sendBuffer[2]='b';
    sendBuffer[3]='c';
    sendBuffer[4]='\0';
    printf(%s,sendBuffer);
    count=count+1;
}
```

In the output, all buffer is printed correctly except the first index. I want 1,2,3 and so on to be printed at the start of the buffer but it does not work. Please Help

Comment: `sendBuffer[1]='a';
    sendBuffer[2]='b';
    sendBuffer[3]='c';
    sendBuffer[4]='\0';` is unnecessary to do inside a loop, since values on the right hand side are constants. Also, the max value of 1-digit number is 9, but not 10.

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert that number into a character. A cheap way to do it is:

```
sendBuffer[0] = '0' + count;
```

> is there anyway to display integers greater than 9

If you need that you'll want to shift to more elaborate schemes. For example, if you want to convert an integer 42 into the string "42" you can say:

```
#define ENOUGH ((CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) - 1) / 3 + 2)

char str[ENOUGH];
snprint(str, sizeof str, "%d", 42);
```

Credit for `ENOUGH` goes to [caf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257728/714501).

Comment: Thank you so much :)
it worked fine, but the problem is that when I want to display Integers greater than 9, it starts displaying special characters like ':', ';' and so on.
is there anyway to display integers greater than 9?

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I don't intend to display the integer as a character, rather I want to store the integer in a character array.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan So maybe it's a different question ? As it stands your question says *"I want 1,2,3 and so on to be printed ..."*.

Answer (score 2):

`printf(%s,sendBuffer);` should be `printf("%s",sendBuffer);`

Comment: OP's code wouldn't compile if that were the problem. (Most likely, the posted code is not exactly what he has).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
sendBuffer[0]=count;
```

to

```
sendBuffer[0]='0' + count;
```

i.e. convert the integer 0...9 to the characters '0' ... '9'

Also add a quote i.e. `printf("%s",sendBuffer);`

Answer (score 1):

To convert an integer value to a char representation, add the value of the character '0':

```
sendBuffer[0]=count + '0';
```

Notice that's the character `'0'`, not the number 0.  This is because of how [ascii values](http://www.asciitable.com/) work.  The char with a literal value of 0 is `\0`, the null terminator.  Digit '0' has a literal value of 48, '1' 49 and so on.

This works for the digits 0-9.  You can't put a char representation of a number bigger than that in a single char, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from the question:

> In the output, all buffer is printed correctly except the first
>   index.i want 1,2,3 and so on to be printed at the start of the buffer
>   but it does not work. Please Help

I think her problem is that she does not get any output for the first line. That is because in the first iteration, count is 0, i.e. sendBuffer[0] is 0 which is the '\0' character. Hence the string is treated as empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print the ascii characters corresponding to decimal values 0-9 which are non-printable characters. If you need to print decimal 0-9 then initialise count to 48 which is the ascii decimal code for '0' and change the condition in the while block to count < 58; 57 is the ascii deciaml code for '9'. See below:

```
char sendBuffer[1000];
int count=48:
while(count<58)
{
    sendBuffer[0]=count;
    sendBuffer[1]='a';
    sendBuffer[2]='b';
    sendBuffer[3]='c';
    sendBuffer[4]='\0';
    printf(%s,sendBuffer);
    count=count+1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to store integers greater than 9 as well.

Comment: A char is 1 byte long while the integer is bigger. Hence, you cannot store an integer in 1 byte. You can keep count and buffer separate but still print them together like printf(%d%s, count, sendbuffer);

Answer (score 0):

```
char sendBuffer[1000];

// take fixed stuff outside the loop
    sendBuffer[1]='a';
    sendBuffer[2]='b';
    sendBuffer[3]='c';
    sendBuffer[4]='\0';

// it's best not to rely on order of ASCII values

for(char* numbers="0123456789"; *numbers!=0; numbers++){// use for loop for numbers
    sendBuffer[0] = *numbers;

    printf("%s",sendBuffer);
}
```