# Converting an integer to char by adding '0' - what is happening?

Tags: c, char

I have a simple program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    char chars[] = {'a', 'i'};
    char name[] = "Max";

    name[1] = chars[1];

    printf("name (before) = %s\n", name);

    name[1] = numbers[1];

    printf("name (after) = %s\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running gives:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror ex8_simple.c
> $ ./a.out
> $ name (before) = Mix
> $ name (after) = Mx
> ```

Which is not what I want. I then dug up the question [Store an integer value in a character array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308783/store-an-integer-value-in-a-character-array-in-c) and changed the program like this:

```
name[1] = '0' + numbers[1];  //replacing  >> name[1] = numbers[1];
```

Then it works how I would expect:

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror ex8_simple.c
> $ ./a.out
> $ name (before) = Mix
> $ name (after) = M2x
> ```

I don't understand whats happening under the hoods though, especially the version without `'0' + …` is really strange. Why is the string truncated in that "weird" way to `Mx`?

For reference, this is a simplified version of [exercise 8 of Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex8.html).

Comment: pipe the output of the program to `hexdump -C` and look at the output. Ascii value for character `0` is `48` (dec) by adding 2 to `48` you get ascii value `50` which is the character for 2.

Comment: This is related to Ascii code. If you declare `int numbers[] = {'1',' 2', '3', '4', '5'};` then you do not need to add `'0'` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each symbol has an numeric representation, so basically each char is a number. Here is the table of characters and its values.

[image]
<sub>(source: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif))</sub>

So, in your code `name[1] = numbers[1];`, you assign `name[1]` to `2`, which is equal to symbol `STX` in the ASCII table above, which is not a printable character, thats why you get that incorrect output.

When you add `'0'` to your `name[1]`, it is equal to `add 48 to 2`, so the symbol with the number `50` is `'2'`, that's why you get that correct output.

Answer (score 4):

> *Which is not what I want.*

but, you've written code for that only. Let me explain both the scenario.

- In case of

  ```
  name[1] = chars[1];
  ```

`name[1]` or `a` is getting replaced with `chars[1]` or `i`. So, the o/p is `Mix`.

- In case of

  ```
  name[1] = numbers[1];
  ```

`name[1]` or `a` is getting replaced with `numbers[1]` or 2, (not `'2'`), which is non-printable.<sup>(#note)</sup> So, the output is `Mx`.

However, in your second approach,

```
 name[1] = '0' + numbers[1];
```

you're storing the ASCII equivalent value of `'2'`, by adding `'0'`. So, the print contains the `character` representation of `'2'` in the output.

**Alternative approach:**

If you modify yout `int` array to store the decimal equivalent of `char` representation of digits `0-9`, then you don't need to add a `'0'`, like

```
int numbers[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'};
```

and

```
name[1] = numbers[1];
```

will give you the desired o/p.

---

Suggestion : Remember, array index in `C` is `0` based.

# NOTE : See this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for reference.

Comment: Ah, I see, the '2' is not printable. But what happens when I do `'0' + 2` why does that make the char printable?

Comment: @Max `'0'` is decimal 48, and `'2'` is decimal 50. hope you got the connection.

Answer (score 3):

In this line: `name[1] = numbers[1];` , you are assigning an `int` value to a `char name[1]` , so that int value in `numbers[1]` is considered as the Ascii code of some char, and that char is stored in `name[1]`.

When you do  `name[1] = '0' + numbers[1];` , then the number(2) is added to ascii code of the number `0`, and therefore you get the actual number. The ascii code of `0` is 48, add 2 to it, you get `50`, which is the ascii code for `2`.

Previously, when you had assigned only `name[1] = numbers[1];`, without the `0`, the char with ascii code `0` was printed. Since it is not a proper printable character, there was nothing displayed (in my machine it was displayed as some wierd emoticon).

Comment: Thanks great explanation!