# strcat C not printing and int to char*

Tags: c, casting, strcat

I'm trying first to generate a random number and cast it to a string. It does it properly but the compiler gives "warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size". And then, the main issue here is that I'm trying to concatenate strings to build a response, but for some reason not even the first strcat works and it just halts there.

```
char *name, *cseq;
srand (time(NULL));
char *session = (char*) ( rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1) + 1000 );

char* response = "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\nCSeq: ";                     
strcat( response, cseq );                   
strcat ( response, "\n" );                      
strcat ( response, "Session " );
strcat ( response, session );                       
strcat ( response, "\n\n" );

printf("Response: %s", response);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't do it "properly";  your code is very broken. Compilers are not trying to be funny when they emit warnings, they generally know what they're speaking about and it's *you* who need to figure out what is wrong with your code that causes it to trigger a warning. Because there should be none.

In your case, this code for instance:

```
char *session = (char*) ( rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1) + 1000 );
```

is not valid, and using `session` as if it points at a valid string will most likely invoke undefined behavior.

You cannot "cast" things into strings in C, unless they're 0-terminated arrays of bytes describing characters in the expected encoding to begin with.

You need to *create* the string from the random number, using e.g. `sprintf()` or something like it:

```
const int session_id = rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1) + 1000;
char session[32];

snprintf(session, sizeof session, "%d", session_id);
```

Of course, once you start using `snprintf()` you might just as well use it for all the formatting, and drop `strcat()` which is a pretty sharp-edged tool anyway.

Also, as pointed out by simonc, you can't modify a string like you're doing it. You should probably have something like:

```
char response[512];

snprintf(response, sizeof response, "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\nCSeq: %s\nSession %d\n\n",
         cseq, session_id);
printf("Response: '%s'", response);
```

Note that this uses `session_id` from above, but does all the formatting in one call to `snprintf()`, so no need for the temporary string version of the session ID.

Of course, if you want to `return` this out of the function, you need to think about buffer management, you can't return `response` as-is since it's a local variable that will go out of scope when the function exits.

Comment: Thank you almighty C guru,it worked flawlessly. You make it seem so easy haha.

Comment: @PatricioJerí Thanks! I guess I belong to some (ill-defined) partition of the programming population that actually enjoys string manipulation in C. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
char* response = "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\nCSeq: ";
```

gives you a read-only string literal.  You can't modify the contents of this.

A quick and dirty fix would be to change `response` to be writeable with a hard-coded length:

```
char response[200] = "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\nCSeq: ";
```

A better approach might be to calculate the lengths of the various string components then `malloc` memory for `response`.  If you do this, be sure to call `free` later.

In addition to the problems with `session` that unwind has pointed out, note that `cseq` is uninitialised in your example so dereferencing it will crash.

Comment: I tried this: char response[200] = "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\nCSeq: "; and printing something afterwards to debug, but it wont step past that line.

Comment: Are you sure its not the following line - `strcat( response, cseq );` that is failing?  That attempts to append an uninitialised pointer to `response` so is highly likely to crash.

Answer (score 0):

With the following

```
char *session = (char*) ( rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1) + 1000 );
```

you're interpreting the random number as a memory address, which is legal but probably not what you wanted to do.
The result is that you dump random memory into the response, obtaining if you're lucky only garbage, and at worst segmentation faults.
If you want to convert it to a string (e.g. 1234 -> "1234") you should use something like

```
char session[6];
snprintf(session,6, "%d", rand() % (9999 - 1000 + 1) + 1000 );
```

(see also previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)).