# Converting an int to a string in C, securely

Tags: c, string, string-formatting, unsigned

According to a [top answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257728/384954) this is what I should do to convert an integer to a string in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>

#define digits(x) ((int)((ceil(log10(abs(x)))+1)*sizeof(char)))

int main () {
    int a = 345908220;
    long b = 23094809284358;
    unsigned int c = 3456789234;
    uint8_t d = 242;
    int64_t e = -840958202029834;

    int dstr_len = digits(a) + digits(b) + digits(c) +
                   digits(d) + digits(e) + 5;

    char dstr[dstr_len];
    sprintf(dstr, "%d %ld %u %u %" PRIu64, a, b, c, d, e);

    printf("%s\n", dstr);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this seems ridiculously inefficient. I have to link my program to libmath, and make **three** math calls for every integer that I want to print. Also note that I had to add `5` to my buffer and not just `1` for the `NUL` terminator, by counting the number of spaces in my format string. This also seems error-prone, and could lead to a buffer overflow.

So, is there any nice, standard function, that will compute the size of my buffer for me?

I'm trying to write secure C.

Comment: You can always write your own.  It's not that hard (and can be quite efficient), though thought is required to deal with the "edge" cases such as large 64-bit values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler has `snprintf()` available, you can request the formatted buffer length and then allocate accordingly:

```
int dstr_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d %ld %u %u %" PRIu64, a, b, c, d, e) + 1;

char dstr[dstr_len];
//
// NOTE: variable-length arrays are NOT supported in all compilers!
// A more portable solution is:
//
// char *dstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * dstr_len);

snprintf(dstr, dstr_len, "%d %ld %u %u %" PRIu64, a, b, c, d, e);

// free(dstr);
```

Comment: Excellent. I found `asprintf`, but it's not standard, and always requires dynamic allocation. This is standard, and doesn't strictly require dynamic allocation. Love it.

Comment: Yes, hense the `+1` on the return value.

Comment: sizeof(char) is by definition "1" so there is no need for it in the malloc, just `char * dstr = malloc(dstr_len);` is enough

Comment: @JohnHascall: `sizeof(char)` is indeed 1, but that does not guarantee a  `char` is **1 8bit byte**. Consider systems where `CHAR_BIT > 8`, meaning `char` is more than 8bits in size. `malloc()` deals in 8bit octets, but `snprintf()` deals in `char`, so it would be more accurate to use `malloc((CHAR_BIT / 8) * dstr_len);` instead. Most developers assume `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which is true on most systems, but not all systems.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, That is completely incorrect.  malloc allocates 'bytes' where a byte is however much is required to hold a char.

Answer (score 2):

You can use snprintf for this.  From the manpage:

> The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size bytes (including the teriitminating  null  byte  ('\0')).   If the output was truncated due to this limit then the return
>          value is the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have  been
>          written  to the final string if enough space had been available.  Thus, a return value of size
>          or more means that the output was truncated.

Thus you can call it with 0 for the size and capture the return value then allocate based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asprintf`, which allocates a large enough output string for you.

Don't forget to **free** the output string, because it is dynamically allocated.

`asprintf` is available on Mac OSX, Linux, and BSD. The [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-142/openssh/openbsd-compat/bsd-asprintf.c) is available from Apple if you wish to use it on other platforms.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main () {
    int a = 345908220;
    long b = 23094809284358;
    unsigned int c = 3456789234;
    uint8_t d = 242;
    int64_t e = -840958202029834;

    char *dstr;
    asprintf(&dstr, "%d %ld %u %u %" PRIu64, a, b, c, d, e);
    if (dstr == NULL) {perror(NULL), exit(1);}

    printf("%s\n", dstr);
    free(dstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most C "runtime environments" are at most 64 bits. You could test that `int`  is at most 64 bits (with `<stdint.h>` and `<limits.h>`) then use `snprintf` (not `sprintf`  which is unsafe and deprecated) on a large enough buffer (32 bytes is more than enough for 2<sup>64</sup> in decimal).

See Posix spec on [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/limits.h.html) which define `WORD_BIT` so

```
#if WORD_BIT > 64
#error cannot compile on this machine
#endif

char buf[32];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", a);
```

BTW, `<stdint.h>`  defines [several types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html). You might want `intmax_t`