# Converting an integer into a string in C

Tags: c, string, int

How can an integer be converted into a string in C?
Suppose we have an int array:

```
int a[4]={21,1212,53,4131};
```

and each int is to be converted in to strings: "21","1212","53","4131".

Comment: By using e.g. [`snprintf`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: How about `itoa` or `sprintf`?

Comment: itoa is not working here! @binayBaba

Comment: I just need to copy those int to a string and then use those strings separately! @barakmonos
anyway other than sprintf ?

Comment: @barakmanos `itoa()` is not standard `c`. `sprintf()`/ `snprintf()` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Basically use [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) or [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) and/or read the many great detailed answer [that were already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c).

Comment: ...only that `atoi()` is the wrong way around. The link is correct though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

```
char buf[4][5];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  sprintf(buf[i],"%d",a[i]);
```

Or

```
char buf[4][5];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  snprintf(buf[i],sizeof(buf[i]),"%d",a[i]);
```