# Adding int value to a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to add an `int` value in a `char` array. meaning if I have a `1`, I would like to represent it like `'1'`.

I have seen an equation to do this before to get the ASCII code of it. am working with a limited compiler for C so I don't have the luxury to use functions like `sprintf()` or others. it has to be in the form of an equation that I must implement. Can anybody help me with that.

example of what I'd like to do

```
char array[2];
char array[0] = 1 * (equation);
```

and then `array[0]` should have the value '1'.

Comment: itoa is one way  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with values in range 0-9, you can use

```
array[0] = 1 + '0';
```

This will give you the `char` representation (`'1'`)of `int` values (`1`).

Comment: when I do this it prints out a '1' and then some strange characters next to it

Comment: @user3567826 you need to null terminate the array to use it as a string. Try adding `array[1] = 0;` after `array[0]` and check. :-)

Comment: seems to be working great! but how can I make it support ints larger than 9?

Comment: @user3567826: You can't; an integer larger than 9 won't fit in a single character if you're using decimal. If you use hexadecimal, you can store values from 10 to 15 as `'A'` through `'F'`. Of course you can store the value `10` as the two-character sequence `'1', '0'` -- but that's not what you asked for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add ASCII value of 0 to the already present number.

Suppose int t=8; then we can convert t to char as follows

```
int t=8;

char s= t + 48; //ASCII value of '0'
```

So your equation should be

> char s= integer + 48 ;