# from int to char, Sending byte by byte

Tags: c++, c, char, int

I was wondering how can I convert a 6 digit number for example `198200`, to a `char` for example `Tx = ['1', '9', '8', '2', '0', '0']`, so that later I can for example write:

```
*p_tx_buffer++ = Tx[2];
```

And then I will only send a the `'8'`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: Use [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c is a much more complete dupe.

Comment: @vsoftco Note: suggested dupe is for `C++` and this post is ill tagged `C/C++` post.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I didn't see it's tagged `C` also.

Answer (score 1):

A simple quick solution is

```
char array[100];
int number = 198200;
if (snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "%d", number) >= sizeof(array))
    fprintf(stderr, "there is not enough room for the string\n");
else
    fprintf(stdout, "array[2] = %c\n", array[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I want to get only the saved char, like only Tx, because i want to use it later, what should I consider ? because with the code you have provided i believe i can only print it ,i want it as a saved variable? Thank you

Comment: What do you think `array` is?