# Change int to some string

Tags: c

So I tried to get a number(int) from the user and move the number from the integer to the empty string, and than i need to print it like a string. help?

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define  CHAR_LENGTH 100
int main()
{
    int num =0,units=0 ,length=0,counter =0,i=0 ;
    char charNumber[CHAR_LENGTH]={0};
    printf("enter some number(positive or negative)\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while (num != 0)
    {
        units =0;
        units = num %10;
        num = num / 10;
        charNumber[i]= (char)units;
        counter++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s",charNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: `charNumber[i]= (char)units + '0'`;

Comment: You need a string terminator `'\0'`

Comment: @WeatherVane The array is initialized to `0` already..

Comment: Agreed, but when another number is entered? It is good practice to insert the terminator anyway.

Comment: Well, it happens only once in this program..

Comment: What is the expected behavior ? And what do you get ? Give an example of execution scenario fro both expected behavior and for what do you get.

Comment: This also prints the number in reverse, and mis-handles negative numbers.

Comment: Just a FIY ... the number, while being typed on the keyboard by the user, is a string to begin with. What you are doing is having the runtime library (`scanf()`) convert that string to an integer, then your program convert the integer back to a string. Maybe, just maybe, you can make use of the original string (from the keyboard) directly :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an int to string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to write an algorithm yourself? If not, use `itoa` function of C standard library (although it's not so standard, but some libraries include it).

You can also use `sprintf` like this:

```
int value = 2016;
char my_string[64];

snprintf(my_string, 64, "%d", value);
```

Check out these links as well:

- [How to convert an int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8257714/4354477)
- [`itoa` on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa)

Comment: @EdHeal, I was just editing my answer to add this :)

Comment: Except that itoa is *not* a standard C function. snprintf is a better way in C.

Comment: This is a fairly common beginning programming assignment, so there's a reasonable chance that's not an allowed approach.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

(1) Negative numbers.  `if (num < 0) { printf("-"); num = -num; }`
    (*yes, I ignored the obvious corner case*)

(2) You print the digits in the backwards order.

(3) You need to add '0', as in `charNumber[i]= (char)units + '0'`