# Is snprintf(NULL,0,...); behavior standardized?

Tags: c, standards, stdio

On Linux it returns the number of characters that would be printed.

Is this standardized behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

From **7.21.6.5  The snprintf function**, N1570 (C11 draft):

> The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output
>   is written into an array (speciﬁed by argument s) rather than to a
>   stream. **If n is zero, nothing is written, and s may  be  a  null 
>   pointer**. Otherwise,  output  characters  beyond  the n-1st  are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character
>   is written at the end of the characters actually written into the
>   array. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the
>   behavior is undefined.

It's a useful method to find the length of unknown data for which you can first find the necessary length and then allocate the exact amount of memory. A typical use case is:

```
char *p;

int len = snprintf(0, 0, "%s %s some_long_string_here_", str1, str2);

p = malloc(len + 1);

snprintf(p, len + 1, "%s %s some_long_string_here", str1, str2);
```

Comment: Good, but what exactly are you quoting?

Comment: [C11 Draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), Section 7.21.6.5.

Answer (score 3):

According to [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) it is standardized by POSIX & by C99. That man page also says:

> ```
>    Concerning the return value of snprintf(), SUSv2 and C99 contradict
>    each other: when snprintf() is called with size=0 then SUSv2
>    stipulates an unspecified return value less than 1, while C99 allows
>    str to be NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as always)
>    as the number of characters that would have been written in case the
>    output string has been large enough.  POSIX.1-2001 and later align
>    their specification of snprintf() with C99.
> ```

So `int i=snprintf(NULL, 0, "`*some-format-string*`",`.... `);` should put in `i` a negative number on failure, or a non-negative output size on success.

<sup>(I don't exactly know what happens if the output size is bigger than `INT_MAX` which is *very* unusual; I guess that it would be a failure case)</sup>