# function opposite to atoi()?

Tags: c, atoi

I would like to convert an integer to a string like:

```
int a = 12345
```

coverts to

```
char b[6] = "12345"
```

basically the opposite of the atoi function that converts a string to an integer.

Comment: sprintf() with `%d`?

Comment: `char b[5]` --> `char b[6] ` or more

Comment: `char *t = s+sizeof(s) ;  *--t = 0 ; do { *--t = (n % 10)+'0'; n/=10; } while (n);` (add a test for negatives) the string number is at `t`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

Example

```
char str[10]; 
sprintf(str,"%d", 12345);
```

Comment: Thanks for the signature but how do you use it?

Comment: char str[10]; sprintf(str,"%d", 12345);

Answer (score 4):

source: [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/)

> char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base )
>
> Convert integer
>   to string (non-standard function) Converts an integer value to a
>   null-terminated string using the specified base and stores the result
>   in the array given by str parameter.
>
> If base is 10 and value is negative, the resulting string is preceded
>   with a minus sign (-). With any other base, value is always considered
>   unsigned.
>
> str should be an array long enough to contain any possible value:
>   (sizeof(int)*8+1) for radix=2, i.e. 17 bytes in 16-bits platforms and
>   33 in 32-bits platforms.

But is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++

A standard-compliant alternative for some cases may be sprintf:

- sprintf(str,"%d",value) converts to decimal base.

Answer (score -3):

Use itoa(). That should do the trick.(Only some compilers have it)

Comment: Not standard...

Comment: @ringøwhat do you mean?

Comment: [This is what I mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)