# C system call I/O and sscanf practice

Tags: c, io, system-calls, scanf

I'm trying to write a C program that take input and output using system calls (`read` and `write`). However, I also want to convert using `sscanf`. The program will input a starting and ending value and will count to that ending value. I'm trying to use `sscanf` to convert.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){                                                
    char beg[5];                                                                
    char stop[5];                                                               
    int i, start, end;                                                          

    write(1, "Starting value: ", 16);                                           
    read(0, beg, 4);                                                            
    sscanf(beg,"%d",&start);                                                    

    write(1, "Ending value: ", 14);                                             
    read(0, stop, 4);                                                           
    sscanf(stop,"%d",&end);                                                     


    int dif = end - start;                                                      
    if (dif >= 0){                                                              
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++){                                         
            write(1, &i, sizeof(i));                                            
        }                                                                       
        write(1, "\n", 1);                                                      
    }                                                                           
    return 0;
}
```

Desired output:

```
Starting value: 1
Ending value: 4
1 2 3 4
```

However, nothing prints for the count (it works if I used `printf("%d ", i);`)

Comment: `read(0, beg, 4);` beg is NOT NUL-terminated. [buufer your input]

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
int i;
write(1, &i, sizeof(i));
```

I guess you believe this is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d", i);
```

But it is not!

Whereas `printf()` will *format* its arguments into human-readable ASCII text, `write()` does no such thing.  Instead, it writes raw bytes directly in a file as binary, machine-readable data.

Just use `printf()`.

And as for this:

```
write(1, "Starting value: ", 16);
```

That's bad code.  Instead:

```
puts("Starting value: ");
```

Comment: @Jakeeln: Why?  Is it that you are doing a school assignment and are not allowed to use `printf()`?  If so, you should mention this in your question.

Comment: No not for school, i meant the reason for the post was specifically to better understand the use of system calls.

Comment: i guess a specific question, how would you change `write(1, &i, sizeof(i));` to print the value?

Comment: @Jakeeln: For that you first need to convert the integer to a string, then `write()` it.  As for how to do the first step, it's covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c