# 'itoa': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated

Tags: c, itoa

I'm trying to convert an `int` into a `string` by doing this:

```
int id = 12689;
char snum[MAX];
itoa(id, snum, 10);
```

I get the following error:

> 'itoa': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C and C++ conformant name: _itoa.

Comment: Are you using visual studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: Well, do what the compiler tells you.

Comment: @machine_1 yes visual studio

Comment: Regardless of what Visual Studio tells you, there's *no* standard function named `itoa` or `_itoa`. Unless you are looking for something fancy, `snprintf()` should be good enough.

Comment: Then use `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` before including header files.

Comment: Perfect thanks guys got it fixed

Answer (score 12):

That is MSVC doing that to you. If you add the following line *before* any library `#include`s

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
```

the warning is suppressed, similar for many other functions too.

Moreover if you add these two lines as well, MSVC will stop telling you to use `scanf_s` instead of the standard function `scanf` (and others).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

Answer (score 5):

Please use `snprintf`, it is more portable than `itoa`.

```
char buffer[10];
int value = 234452;
snprintf(buffer, 10, "%d", value);
```

[itoa is not part of standard C, nor is it part of standard C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/); but, a lot of compilers and associated libraries support it.

Comment: The comment to rename it is just to bring the function name in line with C / C++'s naming conventions with regards to proceeding underscores `_itoa` preferred over `itoa`; but, in either case, the existence of a `itoa` function in either case is not standard C, even if it is common.  It is compiler dependent, and the kind of code that needs rewritten to make porting your application easier.

Answer (score 1):

There has never been a standard `itoa` function in C standard library. So, trying to use it is not a good idea in any case. In C you have functions from `sprintf` family that will happily perform that conversion for you.