# Convert int to bytes array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to convert an `int` to a `char[4]` where each byte in the `char[4]` contains a decimal value of 2. So in the following example:

```
int p = 2999999;
```

Convert `p` to the array that is identical to `k` where `k` is constructed via:

```
char k[4];
k[0] = 2;
k[1] = 99;
k[2] = 99;
k[3] = 99;
```

How can I do this in C?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no direct conversion. You will have to write code for this.

Comment: what if `p > 99999999`?

Comment: An idea (extremely inefficient) would be to convert the number to string, then split the string into 4 (string) parts, and then convert back each part.

Comment: first convert `int` to `string` and then parse it as per your req. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: "I would like to convert an int to a char[4] where each byte in the char[4] contains a decimal value of 2"  char k[4] = {2,2,2,2}; ??  Please can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: What should happen with negative values like `int p = -2999999;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange problem for me but OK. here's what I would have done:

1. Copy value of `p` so that it can be used later (I assume that this conversion doesn't intend to change its value).
2. Use modulo operation to get 2 last digits
3. cut down the copy of `p` to be able to read next two digits.

So complete answer is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p = 2999999;
    char k[4];
    int p_copy = p;
    int i;
    for(i = 3; i >=0; i--)
    {
            k[i] = p_copy % 100;
            p_copy /= 100;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            printf("k[%d]: %d\n",i, k[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

And for sanity the output:

```
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ gcc test.c -o test
gonczor@wiktor-papu:~/tmp$ ./test
k[0]: 2
k[1]: 99
k[2]: 99
k[3]: 99
```

Comment: I've changed looping order. Is there anything else?

Comment: Oh, yes. I've included them in my test code but not here. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: It's not a strange operation at all. This is representation is called ["Binary Coded Decimal"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Comment: I haven't though about this. OK. makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

for (i =4; i--; k[i] = p % 100, p /= 100);

Comment: Could you be specific?

Comment: Considering `int k[5];` (one extra (last) element), this does the trick (after all the corrections). +1.

Comment: Sorry; typed on phone. The syntax is otherwise fine. Does not handle p < 0. Does not handle p > 99999999. Does not declare (i). Is that your problem?