# How to store a number in strings in c

Tags: c

I am new to C and i am trying to store Integer in a string.Can anyone put lights on how i could do this.

my code:

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
str[0] = 'h';

sprintf(&str[1], "%d", 34);
str[2] = 'e';


expected output: h34e
output: h3e
```

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, the string gets terminated later. sorry i meant to sprint

Comment: @JohnnyMopp becaue it's using the wrong index (2 instead of 3), the string remains '\0'-terminated, because `sprintf` writes the '\0'-terminating byte at index 3. So in this case, the code does not yield undefined behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `malloc` for that tiny amount of memory, a `char str[5]` would
also do the job in this case. Also bear in mind that you [shouldn't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And `sizeof(char)` is always 1,
so you can omit that as well. You should also always check the return value of
`malloc`:

```
char *str = malloc(5);
if(str == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}
```

And don't forget to free the memory.

But I'm digressing now. The problem in your code problem is that

```
str[2] = 'e';
```

is overwriting the 4 in `"h34"`. That's why the output is `h3e`. After the
`sprintf` call the memory looks like this:

```
index     0     1     2     3      4
       +-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
       | 'h' | '3' | '4' | '\0' | ??? |
       +-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

The correct index is `3`, not 2:

```
char str[5];
str[0] = 'h';

sprintf(&str[1], "%d", 34);
str[3] = 'e';
str[4] = '\0'; // making sure to terminate string

puts(str); // output is h34e
```

If you append a character, you must not forget to set the
`'\0'`-terminating byte. That's what I'm doing in `str[4] = '\0'`. In your
example you were "lucky" because you didn't overwrite the `'\0'`-terminating
byte, so the string was still terminated correctly.

Also `snprintf` takes the length as well, without the length you should use
`sprintf`. In this case you can use `sprintf` because you know the size of the
buffer and the length of the number, you know that you are not going to write
beyond the limits, that's why in this case it's OK to use `sprintf` instead of
`snprintf`.

But of course you can do that in two lines of code:

```
char str[5];
sprintf(str, "h%de", 34);
```

But I also like your original code because it forces you to think about how to access
elements of the array with indices and how strings are stored in memory. As an exercise this is good. For more serious projects, I wouldn't create strings in such a way. I'd use the one-liner solution.

Comment: @user3121023 yes, but this is a nice excessive for learning how to use array indices, that's why I used the same code as the OP.

Comment: Casting of the malloc does not matter. It did matter 20 years ago when functions without the prototype were allowed. Now if you use less than 20 years old compiler and do not stick to the  obsolete pre c99 standards  - it is safe.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 still, it's bad C style. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc we link to this page at least 100 times every day for a reason.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for fixing my grammar and typos, boy I had a lot of them this time. I usually read my answers before posting, but this time I missed a lot of errors.

Comment: You're welcome. My main reason for editing was the confusing "don't have to forget" statement. At first I thought you wrote that you don't have to add the null byte and got it backwards.

Comment: @Pablo old obsolete topic. You may not like it but it is only your personal opinion nowadays. You can link it even billion times a day, but it was the truth when malloc could be called without the stdlib.h included. Now it is not possible as you will get the error. The rest is only about someone's liking. Same as sizeof into or sizeof(int)

Comment: You might want to advise the use of `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` for safer programming, with better protection against undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...)` in one line like this:

```
snprintf(str, 5, "h%de", 34);
```

`snprintf` will terminate your string with `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **itoa()** function. This function in C language converts int data type to string data type(Null terminated string). Syntax for this function is given below.

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

The third parameter base specify the conversion base. For example:- if base is 2, then it will convert the integer into its binary compatible string or if base is 16, then it will create hexadecimal converted string form of integer number.

**Note: There may be a chance that itoa() function does not work as this function is not a standard function.**