# Conversion of decimal to string

Tags: c, stm32, keil

I'm trying to convert a decimal value into a string. I use the STM32CubeIDE IDE but am getting an error like *'Invalid binary operator'*. I'm able to set `&n` to the decimal value `3695`.  I need to convert that into a string. How would I do that?

```
void main() 
{

    uint8_t TxArr;
    uint16_t Data;
    int a[10];
    int i;
   while (1)
   {
     HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,0x16, &TxArr, 1, 1000);
     HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0x17, &Data, 2, 1000);
     for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
      a[i]=Data%10+0x30;     //value in Data is 3695.
      Data=Data/10;
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, a[i], 11, 100);
      HAL_Delay(300);
      }

      }
```

Comment: please format your code properly, this is just unreadable. (hint it's probably something with mixing tabs and spaces)

Comment: @TarickWelling,thanks for your response sir.First time i asked question in this environment,so sorry for the mistake done in writing code.Now i edited it please check it once.

Answer (score 3):

The error is produced by:

```
n = n / 10;
```

What this would do if `n` was a pointer (`int* n`) is that it would repoint `n` to a location one tenth the original number. [You will need to begin using normal array operators if you want your code to work properly.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm)

The second problem you have is the following:
You declare `n` as a array of 10 integers of type and with `int`.

```
int n[10];
```

Then in your for loop you try to do this:

```
n > 0;
```

This is an invalid operation as `n` wil decay into a pointer and as such the address of your array is compared to `0`. This will always evaluate as TRUE!

A good way to convert a integer to a string (char array) is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257728/8548828).
In your sitaution that would be

```
int yourToBeConvertedNumber;
char str[INT_MAX]; // or any other reasonable upper bound you have set for the input data.
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", yourToBeConvertedNumber);
```

Comment: `str[INT_MAX];` - this is creating a VERY VERY BIG string. You don't want `INT_MAX` bytes, you want enough bytes to store `INT_MAX` in base-10 representation, that is `log10(INT_MAX)`, which is like 10 characters for 32-bit `int`. So `char str[11]` is enough.

Comment: @KamilCuk feel free to add to the post. It was just a quick bit of code which at least didn't have a buffer overflow in it. But yeah `INT_MAX` is quite stupid.

Comment: @Tarick Welling,thanks for your response sir.I used this snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%d", yourToBeConvertedNumber);  but it just display  ASCII value ,I want to transmit this ASCII value in matlab for that we have to store this value in a array,so how can i do it?

Comment: of course it displays garbage. What is `0x30 + 9` and what is different when you do `0x30 + 10`? You didn't read/do the last part of the answer

Comment: @Tarick Welling,thanks for your quick response sir,0x30+9 this is for taking ascii value of 9.Initially i get decimal value like 3695 and converting each digit into ascii by seperating each digit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, to convert an integer to a string, you can use the `sprintf` function. It should be available in `newlib`and even `newlib-nano` standard C libraries.

However my guess here is that you have an array of integers where each element is a number between 0 and 9 ?

If this is true you have several issues: you seem to handle the variable `n` like an integer and not an address. Also your string should be one element longer and composed of chars.

You may do something like this:

```
char a[11];
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   a[i]=n[i]%10 +'0'; 
}
a[11]='\0';
```

Comment: @Petitjean thanks for your  response sir,i refer your suggestion and made some changes in my code as given above,please check it once and correct me.By this code i am getting ascii value of each digit and stored in a array but when i am trying to check it on hyperterminal or docklight ,it shows garbage value.Any suggestion over it sir?