# Is there any proper way how to put integer into string? [C]

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer, c-strings

I have code like this:

```
char str[100];
int r = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < i;k++){
    str[r++] = y[k];
    sprintf(str[r], str, x[k]);
    r++;
}
```

I want in **array y** I have only alphabetic characters(e.g C,D...) and in **array x** I have only numbers. I want to make string like "C50D80E20" etc."
But I dont know how to put interger into string(I know I´m using sprintf wrong and also that it shouldn´t be used in this case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an int to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: You can convert digit to char by adding '0'.
For example:  
char y= 6+'0'; Makes y holding the char '6'.

Comment: @YanBir in ASCII yes but generally not

Comment: @YanBir It only works for numbers less than 10 :/ I need somethig that can work for any number, but thanks for help.

Comment: @P__J__ What it means in generally? Could you give an example of not. (Considering the number is less then 10)

Comment: @P__J__ *in ASCII yes but generally not*  No, it works in any [C character set](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p2): "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."  But it only works for the `int` values `0` through `9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char s[N];

    char a[] = "CDE";
    int  b[] = { 50, 80, 20 };

    int pos = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i + 1 < sizeof( a ); i++ )
    {
        pos += sprintf( s + pos, "%c%d", a[i], b[i] );
    }

    s[pos] = '\0';

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
C50D80E20
```

This statement

```
s[pos] = '\0';
```

is required only in the case when there are no values to append to the array `s` that is when none call of `sprintf` was executed.

If you want to get a string like this

```
C50 D80 E20
```

then just write for example

```
pos += sprintf( s + pos, "%c%d%c", a[i], b[i], ' ' );
```

And if you want to remove the last space character then instead of

```
s[pos] = '\0';
```

write

```
s[ pos == 0 ? pos : pos - 1 ] = '\0';
```

Instead of the function `sprintf` you could use the function `snprintf`. But it does not resolve the problem if you allocated not enough memory for the result string because in any case you will not get the expected result in such a case.

As for the function `itoa` then it is not a standard C function.

Comment: Great, what if want to add " " after each combination?
Following code does not seem to work.
char c = ' ';
 pos += sprintf( s + pos, "%c%d%c", a[i], b[i] , c);

Comment: @ThomasCodesThings I do not see any problem. Just use pos += sprintf( s + pos, "%c%d%c", a[i], b[i], ' ' ); That is use the character literal ' ' (not the string literal " ").

Comment: Whenever I do that program drops.

Comment: @ThomasCodesThings It seems you are doing something wrong. Maybe you  incorrectly specified the condition in the loop. Or your array a contains less characters than the array size and so on. Just copy and paste my example. Pay attention to that you need to use the character literal ' ' not the string literal " ".

Comment: I slightly modiefied8your example and it works fine I just want to make final string like "C50 D80 E20"  etc.

Comment: I had less memory allocated that I throught. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itoa()`. 
Somthing like that:

```
itoa(y[k], str[r++], 10);
```

Here's [a link](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-itoa-function/) about `itoa()`.

**UPDT:**

Or as correctly commentator marked - you can use `int + '0'`

Comment: Note that `itoa()` is not a standard C library function.  Function varies by implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any proper way how to put integer into string? [C]

Use `snprintf()`.
Check results.

```
char str[N];
int len = snprintf(str[r], sizeof str, "%d", x[k]);
if (len < 0 || (unsigned)len >= sizeof str) Handle_Error();
```