# How do I subtract 1 from an array of integers

Tags: arrays, c, subtraction

I am learning C in school, and I am having a little difficulty on my project.
Basically, I am writing a function that gets a string containing a positive integer. The function subtracts 1 from that integer and puts the obtained value in the string.

So , if I have this ;

```
char nums[] = "2462";
```

how do I write a function that will subtract 1 from the integer, so that the result is "2461"??

Comment: convert to integer subtract, convert back to string. Or handle the subtract & carry on characters manually

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You may be interested in the `aoti` family of functions (or `strtol`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert the character array into an integer.

You can use [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) (ASCII to Integer), but because it returns 0 on error there's no way to tell the difference between successfully converting `"0"` and an error.

Instead use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) (STRing TO Long integer).

```
// end stores where parsing stopped.
char *end;

// Convert nums as a base 10 integer.
// Store where the parsing stopped in end.
long as_long = strtol(nums, &end, 10);

// If parsing failed, end will point to the start of the string.
if (nums == end) {
  perror("Parsing nums failed");
}
```

Now you can subtract, turn the integer back into a string with `sprintf`, and put it in nums.

```
sprintf(nums, "%ld", as_long - 1);
```

This is not entirely safe. Consider if nums is `"0"`. It only has 1 byte of space. If we subtract 1 then we have `"-1"` and we're storing 2 characters where we only have memory for 1.

For the full explanation of how to do this safely, see [How to convert an int to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c).

Alternatively, don't store it, just print it.

```
printf("%ld", as_long - 1);
```

Comment: In your last `printf` and in your `sprintf` there's a typo: use `%ld`, not `%d`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Can you please explain what does &end(the second argument) and base(the third argument) do? It worked for this problem but I would like to understand more about this function.

Comment: @HayatoKoyama `base` is what base to use in the conversion. If you had a hex string like `2b` you could use base 16 to convert it to 43. `end` stores where the parsing stopped. If you had a string like `1234 and 5678` it would return 1234 and `end` would point at `" and 5678"`. If parsing fails it would return 0 and `end` will point to the entire string. `end` lets you parse multiple numbers out of a string, and also check if the parsing failed.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert string -> int -> string.

You can do this by using [atoi](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) and [sprintf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm).

Simple implementation (far from perfect):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
  int a;
  char b[5];
  a = atoi("2462");
  a--;
  sprintf(b, "%d", a);
  printf("%s\n", b);
  return 1;
}
```