# I have a problem with declaring an array. C language, Atmel Studio

Tags: c, atmelstudio

this is my code and I have a problem with array.

```
int main(void)
{
    PORTD = 0x01;
    LCDOUT();
    
char count = 0;
char firstLine[] = "Number of count";
char secondLine[] = {count};


while (1)
{
    Command(HOME);
    LCD_String(firstLine);
    Command(LINE2);
    LCD_String(secondLine);
    
    if ((PIND&0x01)==0x00) 
    {


        count++;
            _delay_ms(500);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make

char secondLine[] = "0"; when the code starts.

And if ((PIND&0x01) == 0x00)), then

secondLine[] = "1"

secondLine[] = "2"

secondLine[] = "3"

...

...

So in the secondLine, the number of counts can be shown through LCD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an int to string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The function `snprintf()` is supporting your goal.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

It allows to create string representation of parameters.

Make sure that there is enough space in `char secondLine[2];` and that you use the length parameter ( `size_t bufsz` ) to not write beyond.

You will have to do the printing inside your loop, so that the string content is updated along with `count++`.