# Converting a long integer to char array in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, integer

I want to convert this:
int number = 12345678;
to
uint8_t numarray[] = "12345678";

How to make this possible? I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why `uint8_t` rather than `char` which is the normal type for a string? Anyway, use [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

Comment: I think you might be looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257728/19592428

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
    
    int number = 12345678;
    
    char numberArray[10] = {0};
    
    itoa(number,numberArray,10);
    
    printf("Number Array = %s",numberArray);

    return 0;
}
```

I think this code will do what you want

Comment: Note that `itoa` is not a standard C function and will not be available in all cases.

Comment: sprintf(numberArray,"%d" ,number);