# How to hook malloc function on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, shared-libraries, hook

I'm reading the [Driving Compilers](https://fabiensanglard.net/dc/) series of articles by [Fabien Sanglard](https://fabiensanglard.net/about/index.html). In [part 3](https://fabiensanglard.net/dc/cc.php) about **The Compiler** there is an example for hooking [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function. First, an incorrect solution that falls in an infinite recursion is shown:

```c
void* malloc(size_t sz) {
  void *(*libc_malloc)(size_t) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
  printf("malloced %zu bytes\n", sz);
  return libc_malloc(sz);
}
```

The reason for the recursion is that [dlsym](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) function internally calls *malloc*.

After that, a supposedly fixed solution is provided:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = nullptr;

void *malloc(size_t size) {
    if(!real_malloc)  {
      real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }

    printf("malloc(%d) = ", size);
    return real_malloc(size);
}
```

Except that the solution is not really fixed because it suffers from the same problem. If I rename the function from malloc to `my_malloc` for example then it will work, but it is no longer a hook because the other software uses `malloc` but not `my_malloc`. Is there any solution to the problem?

Comment: Maybe add which libc implementation you are using (e.g. glibc, musl, etc.). I have some doubts that they will behave the same.

Comment: *"dlsym function internally calls malloc"*  Are you sure about that?  glibc 2.17 on CentOS7 doesn't appear to based on valgrind.

Comment: @dbush I'm not sure but this is mentioned in the article. It is possible the infinite recursion to be not the case because putting `printf` at the beginning of the hook prints nothing before the segfault.

Comment: @user17732522 I don't know how to check which is the *libc* implementation on my system but I'm on the latest Ubuntu which according to a web search seems to use *glibc*.

Comment: A little more investigation shows that what really calls malloc and an infinite recursion is the `printf` function but not the `dlsym`. This reduces the question to how to do the printing the right way.

Comment: that should be `printf("malloc(%zu) = \n", size);`

Comment: you could try [`puts`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html), don't know if that internally calls `malloc`, I'd guess not. Might have to get creative with it if you also want to see the size .. print to a local char array perhaps, then `puts` that, or maybe `putchar` one byte of the size at a time ?

Comment: @yano Not really - `printf()` is likely to call `malloc()` itself internally and cause infinite recursion.  `printf()` and all related functions can't safely be used.

Comment: @yano Yes.  `puts()` and, unless you have something platform-specific saying a function is reentrant, the entire list of functions in the C standard, per C11 7.1.4p4:  "The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant ..."

Comment: @AndrewHenle `puts` being a "related function"? Or just the print-to-string functions?

Comment: @AndrewHenle gotcha ,, you're too fast, screwed up the chronology ;) thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more investigation shows that what really calls `malloc` and leads to an infinite recursion is the `printf` function call, but not the `dlsym` as written in the article. This reduces the question to how to do the printing in such a way that this not happens. I came up with the following solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

void* malloc(size_t size) {
  if(!real_malloc)  {
    real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
  }

  static char isPrintF = 0;
  if (isPrintF) {
    return real_malloc(size);
  }

  char* p = real_malloc(size);
  isPrintF = 1;
  printf("malloc(%zu) = %p\n", size, p);
  isPrintF = 0;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Note though, that using a static flag like you do with `isPrintF` isn't multithread-safe.

Comment: snprintf + write maybe?

Comment: @ErkiAring `snprintf()` isn't guaranteed to be work - it's likely to use `malloc()` or similar functions internally.  The only platform I know where `s[n]printf()` is safe to use here is Solaris.  Linux is definitely not safe as glibc's `s[n]printf()` definitely does use `malloc()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

First, per [**7.1.4 Use of library functions**, paragraph 4 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p4):

> The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration.

So you can't safely use *any* function from the C standard and be safe.  You need to rely on platform-specific solutions.

First, you can find what functions your platform allows to be called from within signal handlers - these functions pretty much have to be reentrant.

For POSIX-based systems, which I'm assuming you're using because you use the [POSIX function `dlsym()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/dlsym.html), you can start with [**2.4 Signal Concepts**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) which has an extensive list.

Note that `write()` is on the list of async-signal-safe functions, but `printf()` is not.

So your code

```
static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = nullptr;

void *malloc(size_t size) {
    if(!real_malloc)  {
      real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }

    printf("malloc(%d) = ", size);
    return real_malloc(size);
}
```

can be replaced with

```
static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = nullptr;

void *malloc(size_t size) {
    if(!real_malloc)  {
      static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

      pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
      if(!real_malloc)  {
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
    }

    write( STDOUT_FILENO, "malloc()", strlen( "malloc()" );
    return real_malloc(size);
}
```

Note that I omitted the address - that would need to be converted to a string.  It's not hard to do, and examples on how to do that can easily be found, such as in the answers to [**How can I convert an int to a string in C?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-a-string-in-c).  Note that you can't use any answers there that use a standard library function that isn't async-signal-safe.

And if you're running on Solaris, `s[n]printf()` actually *is* async-signal-safe there.

I also added some protection for multithreaded use - there's a race condition in obtaining the pointer value to the actual `malloc()` that should be protected against, if only because if the pointer value gets corrupted you will likely never be able to reproduce whatever error(s) that causes.

**EDIT**

Per the comment from @ChrisDodd, fixed to address concerns about safety of `dlsym()`:

```
static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void initValues(void) {
    real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
}

void *malloc(size_t size) {
    write( STDOUT_FILENO, "malloc()", strlen( "malloc()" );
    return real_malloc(size);
}
```

Note that the code inside the `malloc()` replacement is now  much simpler - there's no race condition possible.

Comment: per the POSIX spec, dlsym is *not* async safe, so using it could be a problem.  In practice it is only likely to call malloc if called with a handle to library opened by dlopen (ie, not when called with the special handles RTLD_DEFAULT or RTLD_NEXT, as they only look at already fully loaded and resolve objects)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Good point.  Although I'm using async-signal-safe here as a proxy for both being reentrant and "doesn't use `malloc()` *et al*" (using `malloc()` or any related function would make a function async-signal-**un**safe).  `dlsym()` could indeed be dangerous - and it won't be reentrant because it pretty much has to use internal locks to make changes to the process's address space, in addition to its potential use of `malloc()`.  As you said, though, just looking up a symbol should be safe.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I updated the code to address potential `dlsym()` issues.

Comment: Were signal handlers mentioned in the Original Post?