# convert int and char into a string

Tags: c, string, string-formatting

I have int `x` and char `c`.  I want to make a new string called `str` as "x c"; so the int, a space, and the char.

So for example:

```
x = 5, c = 'k'

//concatenate int and char with a space in between.
```

so the line `printf("%s", str)` will print:

```
5 k
```

How do I do this in C code?

Comment: Lookup sprintf()/snprintf: `snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%d %c", x, c);`

Comment: Do you just want to print the "<int> <space> <char>" or do you need the string for other purposes? If the former, you should simply use `printf()` to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) or [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to avoid safety of your code to be built on assumption that your buffer will be always big enough:

```
char str[100];
sprintf(str, 100, "%d %c", x, c);
```

But in case the only purpose of `str` will be to be used it to with `printf`, then just `printf` directly:

```
printf("%d %c", x, c);
```

...just don't use [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) since *"this function is* ***not*** *defined in ANSI-C and is* ***not*** *part of C++"*

These questions might help you as well:
[How to convert an int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)
[Converting int to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
char tmp[32]={0x0};
sprintf(tmp, "%d %c", x, c);
printf("%s\n", tmp);
```

or

```
printf("%d %c\n", x, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

sprintf() can do what you want:

```
sprintf(str, "%d %c", x, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to print the information out, there is no reason (that I can see) to convert the data into a string first. Just print it out:

```
printf("%d %c", x, c);
```