# Casting int to char*

Tags: c

I have a little problem with casting int to char* (string)... is it even possible in C?
I'll try to explain why i need this.

I can cast int to char but I need cast int to char*.

I had a int varriable (int number_of_revisions)
and I need convert this number of revisions to char * becouse I need create a name of file and the number of revision is part of the name.... so there is part of code for better imagination of this problem.

```
int number_of_revision = 970; // 970 just for example
char * version;
char * new_name;
char ch_number_of_rev[4];

version = "0.";
itoa(number_of_revision,ch_number_of_rev,10);
//strcat(version, ch_num_o_rev ); // doesn't work becouse ch_number_of_rev is char and strcat requires char*
```

please I need quick help... Have anybody any idea how to do it? ...

Answer (score 4):

`but I need cast int to char*`

Casting only changes the type - it does not change the value within the variable. If you need to convert an `int` to array of chars (i.e. a string) then use `sprintf` or `snprintf`:

```
char* buffer = ... allocate a buffer ...
int value = 970;
sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
```

[Converting int to string in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c)

Also, you have not allocated any memory for `version` - use malloc and allocate some memory.

Comment: I don't need change the value.. I need convert int to char* or keep it at it is itoa(number_of_revision,ch_number_of_rev,10); but then I will need join variable version which is char* with variable ch_number_of_revision wich is char....

Comment: @user3036674 - the code i posted does what you want i believe. Test it once.

Comment: Thanks I'll try the sprintf() :)

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks, but when I try to use variable "buffer" in strcat() it doesn't work:

Comment: char buffer[3];
        int value = 970;
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
        strcat(version, buffer );

Comment: You have not allocated any memory for `version` - use malloc and allocate some memory.

Comment: Yeah, I allocated memory for "version" later, but still doesn't work.... :(    char * version =(char*) malloc (30+1);

Comment: @user3036674 - You allocated the wrong way i guess - check this code - it works: http://ideone.com/zJFI4j

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` here won't work because you haven't allocated any space to store the result in.  Your `version` is probably in read-only memory anyway, so you'd get a segfault, otherwise you'll get memory corruption.  So make sure to allocate enough space for it, e.g. by using

```
char version[10] = "0.";
```

You may want to read up on pointers first, though.

Comment: Ok I allocated memory for "version" and nothing changed....

Comment: Ok I finaly solve this.. thanks guys for help. There is what I did: char version[40];   char buffer[4];
        int value = 970;
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
        strcat(version, buffer );