# Converting an int to string without using library functions in C?

Tags: c, string, int

How do you convert an int to a string without using library functions in C?

Comment: loop over `char*`: `number = char[i] - '0' * 10` this inside a loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting int to string in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by extracting each bits one by one, like this

```
str[i] = (char)( (num % 10) - 48 )
```

48 has to be subtracted because an integer value changing to character goes through an ASCII conversion. Keeping the above line in a loop, that would run for each digit in the number, should do the trick..

Comment: Better to subtract `'0'` than 48.  Cast `(char)` is not needed.

Comment: That needs to be `( (num % 10) + 48 )`. `0` needs to be translated to `'0'`. You need to add `'0'` or `48` to the number to get that.