# Get a part of an integer in C

Tags: c, integer

I came from python and it was easy to get the middle digit of an integer, for example, from 897 I want the 9:

```
>>> num = 897
>>> num2 = int(str(num)[1])
>>> num2
9
```

But how i can do this on C? It's so difficult to convert into string...

Comment: `snprintf` to get the integer into a string, and `strlen` to help you calculate the "middle". Or if you know the number of digits, divide by `10` in a loop a couple of times, followed by a modulo by `10`.

Comment: @Gianla The formula you showed does not extract the middle digit for an arbitrary number.:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: @Gianla By the way what is the middle digit of a number that contains two digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a single digit as an `int` can be done mathematically:

```
int num = 897;
int dig1 = (num /   1 ) % 10;
int dig2 = (num /  10 ) % 10;
int dig3 = (num / 100 ) % 10;
```

Division by one on the first line is only for illustration of the concept: you divide by n-th power of ten, starting with 10<sup>0</sup> = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the modulus operator (%).

In your case

```
num = 897

lastDigit = num%10; // Which returns 7

lastDigit/= 10;

secondLastDigit = lastDigit%10; //Which returns 9
```

Do this using a while loop for as long as you want. EG.

```
while(num>0)
{
    digit = num%10;
    num/=10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest approximation in C to the given Python fragment, and its `str` operator, is `sprintf`/`snprintf`:

```
int num = 897;
char numstr[30];
sprintf(numstr, "%d", num);
char num2 = numstr[1];
int num2n = num2 - '0';
printf("%d\n", num2n);
```

To guard against buffer overflow, it's safer to get in the habit of using `snprintf` rather than `sprintf`:

```
snprintf(numstr, sizeof(numstr), "%d", num);
```

Instead of `sprintf` and `%d`, some systems provide an `itoa()` function (the opposite of `atoi`) for converting integers to strings, but it's not standard.  For more information about converting numbers to strings, see [Converting int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c).

This is "harder" in C than it is in Python for a couple of reasons.  Constructing strings from numbers typically involves calls to `snprintf`, which is both more flexible and more of a nuisance than just calling `str()`.   You typically have to worry about how big the destination array (here `numstr`) needs to be; this difficulty stems from C's lack of a first-class string type.  And C has no convenience method for converting back and forth between digit characters and their values, so C programmers get used to adding and subtracting the constant `'0'` (or, if they like to make more work for themselves, 48).

(And the other part of the difficulty stems, I guess, from practicality.  C was originally designed for writing operating systems and text editors and system utilities and things.  How often do you need the middle digit of a number, anyway?)