# Using sprintf to convert an unsigned long to char array producing 0

Tags: c

I am trying to convert an unsigned long using the sprintf function in c. Code goes like:

```
char ID[6];
sprintf(ID,"%lu",a.id);
```

`a.id` is a number that is passed in that can range from 0 > but I only want the first 6 regardless. Using `printf("%lu",a.id);` prior to conversion prints the right number but once I try print the string from the char the outcome is `0`. Not too sure why this is happening any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, exact and complete code that anyone can run to see the problem.

Comment: `but I only want the first 6 regardless.` soooo `a.id % 1000000`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: You cannot print a `char` using `%lu` specifier. For functions without parameter list, no conversion to `unsigned long` can be done automatically.

Comment: @Gerhardh: `sprintf(ID,"%lu",a.id);` does not attempt to print a `char`. (Presumably `a.id` is `unsigned long`.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was refering to "once I try print the string from the char the outcome is 0." which sounds that the OP provides a `char`. But maybe they mean the result buffer when they say `char`.

Answer (score 3):

> ...  once I try print the string from the char the outcome is 0

Code is risking *undefined behavior* (UB): buffer overrun, potential wrong specifier.

---

> but I only want the first 6 regardless.

1. Insure the buffer is big enough for 6 characters and a terminating *null character*.

   ```
    //char ID[6];
    char ID[6+1];
   ```
2. Handle `a.id` outside the expected range of `0...999999` with `% some_unsigned_constant`.  This does print the *last* 6.

   ```
   // sprintf(ID,"%lu",a.id);
   sprintf(ID,"%lu",a.id % 1000000u);
   ```
3. As type of `a.id`, not posted, 2 steps may be useful to make sure a matching print specifier is used.

   ```
   // sprintf(ID,"%lu",a.id % 1000000u);
   unsigned long ul = a.id
   sprintf(ID,"%lu", ul % 1000000u);
   ```

---

To print the *first* six, even if outside the 0...999999 range, use `snprintf()` which will print only up to the first 6.

```
   char ID[6+1];
   snprintf(ID, sizeof ID, "%lu", (unsigned long) a.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

And the correct way to do what the OP wants is to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char ID[6];
  unsigned long x = 3453342432;
  
  int r = snprintf(ID, sizeof(ID), "%lu",x);
  
  printf("%d %s\n", r, ID);

 return 0;
}
```

Note that the `snprintf` result is a number of characters that would had been written. It was noted by others that you must reserve one character extra space for terminating `NULL`.

Comment: `NULL` best reserved for pointer contexts - which is not applicable here.  Consider `'\0'` or _null character_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yep.

Comment: @LuisColorado I think you did your comment to someone else. BTW any long will fit in a string much smaller then `32` b.